# How to have all django allauth forms and dialogs to show in a popup

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-allauth

So right now I'm implementing django-allauth on my website by extending my base.html and having the templates show on allauths different URLs like (mydomain/accounts/login/) and so on.

I'm looking for a method to have all of allauths dialogues and forms to show in a modal popup instead, my initial thought was to use ajax calls and I was wondering if there is some easy way to integrate with allauths views that I missed in their docs or some other methods or ideas for doing that?

Anything that could put me on the right path would be nice really, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to check the [login view](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py) and make your own view in the popups that do the same things with [this](https://www.abidibo.net/blog/2014/05/26/how-implement-modal-popup-django-forms-bootstrap/) kind of stuff. I would do that.